# GitHub Actions workflow error: Run Command Timeout! Even if the script did well

Tags: shell, nuxt.js, continuous-deployment, pm2, github-actions

I want to deploy my Nuxt.js application on my remote server each time I commit into repository.
Here is my deploy.yml:

```
name: 'Deployment'

on:
  push:
    branches: ['master']

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Connect to SSH
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: webhostgb.com
        username: root
        key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}
        port: 22
        script: |
          cd whgb-new
          git pull origin master
          npm run build
          fuser -kn tcp 3000
          pm2 restart deploy.sh
```

Basically deploy.sh runs npm start, but I use pm2 to create another process instead of doing the deployment in GitHub actions process

And I after 10 minutes I get this error, even if it did well:

```
err: 4bc06ed9a5a0b2fa431a.js   4.77 KiB      14  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/products/tags/_slug
err: 7bf498872cde31ceb6dd.js   13.3 KiB       7  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/docs/_slug/index
err: 8992f5bd049ebae3c980.js   15.6 KiB       8  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/docs/categories/_slug
err: 8e455a3b7f57d2d0fa08.js   4.53 KiB      13  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/products/index
err: b3a251f0bfe837f702a7.js   1.17 KiB       3  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/articles/_slug/index
err: b68201808fd6f4aec517.js   10.1 KiB       4  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/articles/categories/_slug
err: d7cc3a28494e6a6dcc7a.js   15.3 KiB       9  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/docs/index
err: e0d85ab9fd3f1ed51e0d.js   1.35 KiB       1  [emitted] [immutable]  pages/_
err:               server.js    205 KiB       0  [emitted]              app
err:    server.manifest.json  957 bytes          [emitted]              
err: Entrypoint app = server.js
err: 3000/tcp:           
out:  31207
out: > webhostgb@1.0.0 start /root/whgb-new
out: > nuxt start
out: 
out: ℹ Listening on: http://localhost:3000/
2020/05/31 01:39:05 Error: command timeout
err: Run Command Timeout!
```

Answer (score 17):

I get the same error. I fix it with variable `command_timeout`.

For example :

```
...
port: 22
command_timeout: 200m
...
```

Maybe it can help.

Comment: Hello, @Alexis could you please tell me what does this mean? command_timeout: 200m and what will happen if i do command_timeout: 20sec? 
thanks in advanced

Comment: 200m means 200 minutes, here is the documentation : https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action
If you want 20 seconds, try like this : 20s